# Error al crear un archivo .txt en c++

Tags: c++

El tema es que no crea el archivo, empecé hoy con c++ y la verdad me gusta y no me gustaria rendirme por tremenda pavada, bueno el stack overflow dice que tengo que poner mas cosas xd,

```cpp
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;
    int main() {
    int age;//Guardara la edad
    int month;//Guardara el mes
    int year;//Guardara el año
    int day;//Guardara el dia
    char name[8];//Guardara el nombre
    char surname[13];//Guardara el apellido
    int id_number;//Guardara el numero de documento
  cout<<"Tell me a year of birth: ";cin>>age;
  cout<<"Tell me a month of birth: ";cin>>month;
  cout<<"Tell me a day of birth: ";cin>>day;
  cout<<"Tell me your name: ";cin>>name;
  cout<<"Tell me your surname: ";cin>>surname;
  cout<<"Tell me your number ID: ";cin>>id_number;
    ofstream fs("Document.txt");
    fs << "Name: "<<name;
    fs << "\nSurname: "<<surname;
    fs << "\nAge: "<<age;
    fs << "\nDay: "<<day;
    fs << "\nMonth: "<<month;
    fs << "\nID Number: "<<id_number;
    fs.close();
    cout<<"Perfect, the document has been created!";
}
```

Comment: Haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio, y leé [ask]. En lugar de rellenar con ruido la pregunta, editala y agregá _qué error es el que estás teniendo_ (también en la pregunta: _error al_... no nos da pistas de lo que sucede).

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<stdlib.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    int age;//Guardara la edad
    int month;//Guardara el mes
    int year;//Guardara el año
    int day;//Guardara el dia
    char name[8];//Guardara el nombre
    char surname[13];//Guardara el apellido
    int id_number;//Guardara el numero de documento
    
  cout<<"Tell me a year of birth: ";cin>>age;
  cout<<"Tell me a month of birth: ";cin>>month;
  fflush(stdin); //Elimina el caché
  cout<<"Tell me a day of birth: ";cin>>day;
  cout<<"Tell me your name: ";cin>>name;
  fflush(stdin); //Elimina el caché
  cout<<"Tell me your surname: ";cin>>surname;
  cout<<"Tell me your number ID: ";cin>>id_number;
  
    ofstream archivo; //genera un tipo de elemento, como el int o float, llamado archivo.
    
    archivo.open("Documento.txt",ios::out);
    
    if(archivo.fail()){
        cout<<"No se puedo abrir el archivo."; //Si falla al generar, saldrá esto.
    }
    
    archivo<< "Name: "<<name;
    archivo<< "\nSurname: "<<surname;
    archivo<< "\nAge: "<<age;
    archivo<< "\nDay: "<<day;
    archivo<< "\nMonth: "<<month;
    archivo<< "\nID Number: "<<id_number;
    archivo.close();
    cout<<"Perfect, the document has been created!";
}
```

> Y esto sería, se te generará al lado del .exe o, si ya existe, se remplazará. Si quieres elegir un directorio, debes escribirlo así:

```
archivo.open("C://deskpot//documento.txt",ios::out);
```

> No copies la ruta, me lo he inventado :)